# Splitting an MP3 file and inserting another

Tags: ffmpeg

Using FFMPEG, how would I, at a specified timestamp, insert an mp3 file into a larger file?  I've found links on how to split an mp3 into equal sized chunks, I just need to break the large file at the timestamp specified, insert the second file, and bring the chunks back together into a new file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat demuxer for this.

Create a text file like this

```
file large.mp3
outpoint 250.0
file small.mp3
file large.mp3
inpoint 250.0
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy combined.mp3
```